# Puppet directory environments and the $environment variable

Tags: centos, puppet, facter

Like many (I hope), I am preparing for Puppet 4 by separating out my manifests into environments. I intend on having 3 separate environments: qa, staging, prod. In setting up the manifests initially, I had setup a custom fact for environment to point to the specific environment (i.e. created /etc/facter/facts.d/environment that set environment to prod).

When I run a test using a single manifest that prints out the $environment variable, it gives me the value from my custom fact, but when the agent talks to the Puppet Master, it is still using the default environment "production".

Any idea why this is happening? Is facter not able to be used as an ENC?

Comment: Nope, I haven't been preparing for this. Should I? :)

Comment: Well, if you are in the same boat as I am with the default "single manifest" environment, it can be a pain. Or maybe I never fully explored what it was capable of and backed myself into a corner. Either way.

Comment: @ewwhite Yup, required in 4.0. Upgrade to 3.7 and watch the deprecation warnings fly ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$environment` variable isn't technically a fact - it is set by the agent from its `puppet.conf`, instead of a fact.  You'll need to edit it in the agent's `puppet.conf` instead of `facts.d`.

An ENC can set a node's environment (overriding what the agent selects as its own environment), but the master would need to be the one overriding it, not the agent.